# Как правильно писать номер телефона?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать номер телефона?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На письме номер телефона обозначается так:
"Телефон: (095)339-54-32", либо "Тел.: (095)339-54-32".
После слова "телефон" обязательно ставится двоеточие, даже если слово сокращенное.